# How to store html_entites in mysql as their representations not their value

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I want to store the following:

```
$str= "&#8226; This is a bullet point";
```

in my database as an actual bullet point not as its html_entity value.

I have tried:

```
$new_str = html_entity_decode($str);
```

before I store it in the database, however this seems to only work for certain html_entities for example that would work fine for # or & but not •

Any ideas how I do this?.. regards J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Comment: That's because you are displaying the result in an html document whose encoding has not been set to utf8.

Comment: Thanks @zi42, I like your style. Thanks.